# Combining Windows Installers for Python modules

Tags: python, windows

Is there an easy way to combine several .exe installers for Python packages on Windows into one single installer ? I would like to repackage numpy + scipy + some other more specific Python packages into one .exe.

Comment: I think you can just make a script that executes those 3 installers or unzip the setup and compile the files all together?

Answer (score 0):

If you need a nice offline installer with a "next-next-finish" interface for all modules, use [Inno Setup](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php) or [NSIS](http://nsis.sourceforge.net).
Otherwise, just use a simple script as suggested above.

Answer (score 0):

It's not an `.exe` but you could use a `.bat` file to run easy_install or pip install on a directory of packages. Its probably the quickest way of doing things.

To silently install our dependencies we have that kind of setup with a directory called `modules` which contains all the `.tar.gz` and/or `.egg` files and then the following in `install_modules.bat`

```
@echo off
pushd modules
for /F %%f in ('dir /b') do easy_install -Z -N %%f
popd
pause
```